Material lighting with and without background
I like the lighting on objects surface when there is a bright background. But I want to export this object without the background, and still keep the way the light bounce off the surface. Anyone has any idea how to achieve that? Thanks a lot.



Select the background object, go to the Object Properties and under Visibility uncheck Camera. Then the object has full effect on other objects like being reflected etc. but is not visible.

@GordonBrinkmann that appears to be a complete answer. Please post it as such.

@GordonBrinkmann I tried that one, but it turned out as the second photo above. Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work. or maybe not work in 4.2? The only camera option was Ray visibility, and there is a camera tick beside it. turn that off, and the whole reflection was off.

@Jack First of all, I do not know if this was clear: to make it work you have to turn viewport and render visibility back on in the Outliner. Another thing: are you using Cycles or EEVEE? You did not specify anything in your question. For issues involving reflections etc. this is always important to clarify that, since other than Cycles. reflections not always work out of the box and totally as expected in EEVEE. And if it's EEVEE, the next important thing would be if it is the old version or the new one from Blender 4.2 because they work different now.

@GordonBrinkmannOh damn, I forgot to mention that. it's EEVEE. I try to stick with EEVEE since it's way faster, and with 4.2, it looks almost as good as Cycle. Thanks a lot for a detail answer, man. It's working now.

Here is an example, Suzanne over a blue floor/background (I chose blue to make it even more visible later on that it's the plane and no other reflection). The floor should not be visible in camera, only on the object and in the reflections. First make sure that the floor is generally visible in viewport and render by enabling it in the Outliner.

The quick and easy way (only Cycles)
Go to the Object Properties panel and under Visibility > Ray Visibility disable Camera.

Slightly more inconvenient: EEVEE Next (Blender 4.2)
In Blender's current version 4.2 we already have the option to disable the Ray Visibility for Camera in EEVEE like shown above, but at first the floor is no longer visible (no matter if Raytracing is enabled in the Render Properties or not):

What I do is add a Light Probe object (Shift+A > Add > Light Probe > Sphere) and adjust the values to my liking (mainly Radius, Clipping Start/End) and this is the result with Raytracing disabled:

Unfortunately, if you need/want Raytracing for your EEVEE renders, when you enable it the effect is limited to specular reflection, no diffuse reflection no matter if you choose the Method > Light Probe or Screen-Trace:

More complicated: older EEVEE (4.1x and previous versions)
First of all, old EEVEE had no Ray Visibility > Camera to turn off. So to make the floor invisible to the camera but still have an effect on Suzanne, you have to change the material by adding a Light Path node and using the Is Camera Ray output either as mix factor between the actual material and a Transparent BSDF, with the transparency in the second Shader input of the Mix Shader node, or when your material shader is a Principled BSDF you can take an Invert Color node to switch the Light Path output and plug it into the Alpha channel of the Principled BSDF:

Just like before the invisible plane will not appear in the reflections automatically. You have to add a Light Probe again and adjust the settings. However you will not see the effect in realtime. You have to go to the Render Properties > Indirect Lighting and press Bake Indirect Lighting. The good thing is, after it is baked you would not need the light probe object anymore and could delete it. The bad thing is, this also means dynamic changes in lighting are not possible and you would always have to rebake.

Last but not least: Compositor method after rendering (Cycles + EEVEE)
For this method it does not matter if you are rendering with Cycles, old or new EEVEE - you do not even have to make the floor invisible for the camera (actually it has to be visible to effect the monkey normally). The only problem is that you will not see a result in the viewport since it is done by post processing the rendered image in the Compositor. To make it possible, go to the View Layer Properties, and under Passes > Cryptomatte enable Object.

Then render your image just normal with F12 and go to the Compositor afterwards where you should have Use Nodes and Backdrop enabled. Add a Viewer node to the nodetree so you can see the result in the backdrop.

Now add a Mask > Cryptomatte node - not Cryptomatte (Legacy)! - to the setup, you can leave it unconnected at first. Click on the + button next to the Matte ID field. An eyedropper tool appears, hover over the backdrop image with it and it shows the name of the object you are about to pick. Click on Suzanne and the name of the picked object appears in the Matte ID field. In this case it is just one object, but you can repeat this process for more.

If you now plug the Cryptomatte node with its Image in- and outputs between the Render Layers node and the Composite/Viewer output nodes, you get a masked image where the plane is not visible:

